# Can I import typescript types from a Lambda Layer?

Tags: typescript, lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am attempting to use TypeScript when building Lambda functions but hitting an issue when using a Lambda Layer which is also written in TypeScript.

TypeScript does not recognise the /opt/nodejs/... import for my Layer (as it would running in SAM or AWS) and therefore I am unable to import types which I have defined in the Layer to my Lambda function.

I have tried looking to see if I am able to somehow npm link the layer but I can't seem to get that working because the import is a local path '/opt/nodejs...' and not a just a module name.

Layer:

```js
export interface SomeType {
  someField: string
}
```

Lambda:

```js
import { SomeType } from '/opt/nodejs/myLayer' // this does not work
```

I am just getting the error: `Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/myLayer'.ts(2307)` and I find myself having to suppress this with `// @ts-ignore can be ignored as this is a Lambda layer` but that means I am unable to use the TypeScript types from the layer.

Comment: grab your *edit* section and add it as an answer. putting it on the question itself defeats the purpose of SO

Comment: You're right, I've added that as an answer now, thanks!

Answer (score 16):

I think I may have solved this one, I added the /opt/nodejs... path as a path mapping in tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "paths": {
      "/opt/nodejs/myLayer": ["../../layers/myLayer/src/some-layer-module"]
    }
}
```

I can now import TypeScript types from the Layer and as the import path isn't changed, it will still work in AWS/SAM

Comment: If anyone is still having an issue even after this, do not forget to restart your IDE or TS service. Took me over an hour of searching to figure that one out.

Comment: I've done this but when I do a build it includes the local layer code in the transpiled JS so when I deploy it to Lambda it doesn't use the real layer

Comment: For people running into the same issue as @geoffs3310, the question and answer are here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75568314/10331580