# NodeJS Lambda with layers - How to prevent typescript including the layers in the build

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am writing a NodeJs lambda function in typescript that relies on a Lambda layer in order to work. I have made a directory in my project folder with an example layer and then used the path option in my tsconfig file in order to test it locally. This works fine however, when I build the code to compile the JS it includes my example layer file, so when I deploy the lambda it ignores the real layer. How can I get typescript to ignore the example layer and not include it in the build so that when I deploy it to lambda it uses the real layer?

Here is a simple example of my structure to demonstrate the problem:

```
- layers
- - myLayer.js
- src
- - app.js
```

myLayer.js:

```
Export default function doSomething(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

app.js:

```
const doSomething = require("/opt/nodejs/myLayer");

return doSomething(1, 2);
```

tsconfig.js:

```
{
    "paths": {
        "/opt/nodejs/*": [
            "./layers/*"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered *cleaning up* after typescript, rather than *preventing* typescript from adding the files?

If you are using npm you could try adding a `postbuild` script.
Your `scripts` in your `package.json` might look something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "rm -r ./dist && tsc",
    "postbuild": "cd dist && rm -r ./layers"
}
```